# Add Parameter Value in Message of Jenkins Office 365 Connector

Tags: jenkins

I use the Jenkins Office 365 Connector and it sends messages  of the build status to MS Teams as expected.

Now I want to add the value of a Jenkins job parameter to the message.

My usecase: I use a single job to deploy several services. I want to know in the message which service was deployed.

```
  Notification from Dev_Deploy
  Latest status of build #43

  Status
  Build Success

  Remarks
  Started by user XXX

  Service
  service-abc
```

I've seen in the *Advanced configuration* that there are *Macros* and *Fact Definitions*. Unfortunately there is no documentation in the [plugin docs](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Office+365+Connector+Plugin). Perhaps this configuration could help?

Comment: Found this, but I think it's not released yet: https://github.com/jenkinsci/office-365-connector-plugin/pull/91

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no option to customize the message in the jenkins GUI.

But a custom message can be specified in the pipeline script:

```
steps {
    // some instructions here
    office365ConnectorSend webhookUrl: 'https://outlook.office.com/webhook/123456...',
        message: 'Application has been [deployed](https://uat.green.biz)',
        status: 'Success',
        color: '#0000FF'           
}
```

Hint: The status color is not automatically set. So you have to set the color depending on the status.

[Official documentation](https://github.com/jenkinsci/office-365-connector-plugin#pipeline-step)

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the repository data, you can follow instructions to create a checkout snippet through the Jenkins UI in the configuration.

[image: Jenkins-snippet-generator]

Once you input the correct URL, browser, and so on, you may invoke the office365ConnectorSend plugin. You may adapt the card sent by passing the factDefinitions attribute an array of [name,template] objects as outlined in [Jenkins Docs](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/Office-365-Connector/). You can find an example in the open-source code [readme](https://github.com/jenkinsci/office-365-connector-plugin).

there are some defaulted add-ons, but this should set you on the correct path.

Here is an example of my office365ConnectorSend:

```
office365ConnectorSend (
    webhookUrl: "${webhookURL}",
    color: "${currentBuild.currentResult} == 'SUCCESS' ? '00ff00' : 'ff0000'",
    factDefinitions:[
        [ name: "Commit Message", template: "${commit_message}"],
        [ name: "Pipeline Duration", template: "${currentBuild.durationString.minus(' and counting')}"]
    ]
)
```